# Is Fortran '-align array64byte' is a redundant one when '-align' compile option already exists?

Tags: fortran, intel, compiler-optimization, memory-alignment, intel-fortran

I compiled a Fortran90 based CFD program with options like below

```
mpifort -qopenmp -g -r8 -i4 -traceback -align -warn all -O3 -fPIC -xCORE-AVX512 -mcmodel=large ...
```

And I got following errors when running the program

```
sever(408):fort(2):Subscript #1 of the array IRN_GLOB has value 2,027,162,369 which is greater than the upper bound of 1,007,783,168
sever(408):fort(3):Subscript #1 of the array IRN_GLOB has value -623,258,111 which is less than the lower bound of 1
```

The value `2,027,162,369` and the number of the upper bound `1,007,783,168` are on the order of 32-bit integer's boundary (=2,147,483,647) and it seems pretty typical for this code's thread to have arrays whose number of elements is of this order. So I suspect that something went wrong with the memory stuff, and the code invaded other array's memory trying to access `IRN_GLOB`'s element, thus giving these strange numbers, especially the `-623,258,111`.

So I'm considering re-compiling this program with following options

```
mpifort -qopenmp -g -r8 -i4 -traceback -align array64byte -align all -qopt-zmm-usage=high -vecabi=cmdtarget -warn all -O3 -fPIC -xCORE-AVX512 -march=skylake-avx512 -mcmodel=large ...
```

I added `-align array64byte -qopt-zmm-usage=high -vecabi=cmdtarget -march=skylake-avx512` options. The options following `-align array64byte` are just added expecting to do some optimization work on SKL architecture.

What I'm not sure is will `-align array64byte` option do its work when `-align all` (which is equivalent to `-align`) option already exist. The Intel compiler manual says `-align all` option is equivalent to `-align commons -align dcommons -align records -align nosequence` which is in absence with `-align arraynbyte` option. But since it is 'all' option, I wonder if `-align arraynbyte` option is implied in `-align all` option making additional `-align arraynbyte` option redundant.

Since it takes a 1-2 day for a compiled program to run on the PBS scheduler queue, I want to know whether these options are valid before submitting it.

Comment: You can compile a couple different ways and just compare the binaries to see if it made any difference, without actually running a full benchmark on your cluster!

Comment: @PeterCordes That simple answer didn't come across my mind! Thank you, and I ```vimdiff``` the two compiled files differing only ```-align``` and ```-align -align array64byte``` options and indeed they are different :)

Comment: But different how?  Does the compiler embed the build flags into a section of the binary?  Comparing disassembly would be be more definitive, to show actual differences in code-gen, and/or maybe in symbol addresses.  e.g. diff the `objdump -drwC -Mintel a.out` output.

Comment: BTW, are you sure you need `-mcmodel=large`?  That makes everything slower, including function calls and access to all global vars, especially when combined with `-fPIC`.  If you can use `-mcmodel=medium` (only large statically-allocated arrays go in the "large data" section), that should be better.  Then the compiler can still use normal `call rel32` instructions for function calls instead of moving a 64-bit absolute address into a register and doing an indirect call.  And scalar globals can be accessed efficiently with RIP-relative addressing modes.

Comment: I think the large-PIC code model is even more inefficient than 32-bit-mode PIC, not being able to use relative calls or RIP-relative access to any static data.  It's almost certain that `medium` would be fine unless you have automatically-generated source code with billions of scalar variables and/or gigabytes of code.

Comment: @PeterCordes I compared ```objdum -drwC -Mintel a.out``` results, but since I don't know anything for one layer down to the ```.f90``` codes, such as what compilers do compiling the code and so on, what I can tell right now is just they 'differs' in their ```objdump``` output, too. I have really no idea on 'how differ' sadly.. For ```-mcmodel=large```, you are right. The original compile option was ```-mcmodel=medium```, and I changed it to ```-mcmodel=large``` wishing this would fix the problems I have though I was aware of the fact ```-mcmodel=large``` would much slower, which didn't work.

Comment: If the objdump disassembly differs at all, then yeah it's probably a real difference, not just metadata sections of the executable.  `objdump -d` only dumps the `.text` section.

Comment: Your problem is more likely just from a programming error like an out-of-bound access or failure to allocate or initialize something. Start debugging by all the usual debugging flags `-warn -check`, then proceed with dedicated debuggers, examining the backtrace and so on.